# Scraping data with VBA: Why can't I get access to html elements on certain webpages?

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, getelementsbyclassname

On certain webpages I cannot get access to HTML elements using VBA. What am I doing wrong? For example I have two different pages on the same website.

This code returns number of matches on the page.

```
Sub Oddsportalmatches()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim Matches As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate "https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer/"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document

Set Matches = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("name table-participant")

Debug.Print Matches.Length

End Sub
```

This code returns 0. In fact I cannot get access to any element inside the matches table.

```
Sub Oddsportalmatches()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim Matches As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate "https://www.oddsportal.com/predictions/"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document

Set Matches = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("table-participant")

Debug.Print Matches.Length

End Sub
```

Comment: The page will load and that is the html that is returned to you. However the page will continue to load more elements by using Javascript. You need to figure out a way to detect when all the javascript is finished executing in a VB IE document.

Comment: What info do you want from the page?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I just added "Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))" after "Loop" and it did the trick.

Comment: You don't want to wait longer than necessary so hard coded delays are not optimal.